PowerBi Lat and Long Troubles with Azure Map Model
I am running into an issue with a map I am trying to create. I am using a filled Azure map in Power Bi that includes category labels. My columns for data are 3-digit zipcodes, lat and long, and range of values for provider counts.
The issue is that some of the 3-diigit zips are are correlating to regions outside of the U.S. When I add the latitude and longitude to the map data, the map returns blank if I don't summarize the columns and if I do by showing first lat and first long, it just shows blocks for the filled map instead of a gradient for the whole state(s).
Is there a workaround/better route to have the 3 zips centralized to the US and not be confused on the mapping to where it is putting point in other countries?
Tried setting different calculations (sum, avg, etc...) and using world map model to see if that would make a difference. That did not work either.

Can you please provide some sample data so we can recreate this?
